# Uyuni problems with docker-ce repository

Tags: repository, docker-ce

I'm experiencing a strange issue with Uyuni software distribution. Working with spacewalk i have never had this kind of problem.
We configured many channels with related repos, but we are experiencing problems with Docker-ce repository.
The web ui shows No packages in the docker channel:

[Channels overview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I55Xy.png)

As for the other channels, I have configured a sub channel and its repository

[Repository configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2T4Gd.png)

The real issue is shown when, for the fist time, we start ***spacewalk-repo-sync -c ol8_base_epel_docker_src*** manually:

```
uyuni:~ # spacewalk-repo-sync -c ol8_base_epel_docker_src
20:54:23 ======================================
20:54:23 | Channel: ol8_base_epel_docker_src
20:54:23 ======================================
20:54:23 Sync of channel started.
Retrieving repository 'ol8_base_epel_docker_src' metadata ........................................................................................................................................................[done]
Building repository 'ol8_base_epel_docker_src' cache .............................................................................................................................................................[done]
All repositories have been refreshed.
20:54:26 Repo URL: https://download.docker.com/linux/rhel/8/source/stable/
20:54:26     Packages in repo:                18
20:54:26     No new packages to sync.
20:54:26 
20:54:26   Patches in repo: 0.
20:54:26 Sync completed.
20:54:26 Total time: 0:00:02
uyuni:~ #
```

**Packages in repo: 18** = I'm unable to find those packages in any channel

**No new package to sync** = It says it since the first execution

**Total time: 0:00:02** = Each time says 2 seconds elapsed, even the first time

I also destroyed the Docker Channel and the Docker repo, reconfigured and re-synced ma same behavior happened.

Some suggestions?
Thanks to everyone

OC

Answer (score 0):

I solved my needs on creating the repo. By the way I don't know why this issue occur.

Solution:
Use https://download.docker.com/linux/centos/8/x86_64/stable/

instead of: https://download.docker.com/linux/rhel/8/source/stable/

```
uyuni:~ # spacewalk-repo-sync -c ol8_base_epel_docker
12:20:23 ======================================
12:20:23 | Channel: ol8_base_epel_docker
12:20:23 ======================================
12:20:23 Sync of channel started.
Retrieving repository 'ol8_base_epel_docker' metadata ............................................................................................................................................................[done]
Building repository 'ol8_base_epel_docker' cache .................................................................................................................................................................[done]
All repositories have been refreshed.
12:20:25 Repo URL: https://download.docker.com/linux/centos/8/x86_64/stable/
12:20:25     Packages in repo:                67
12:20:25     Packages already synced:          0
12:20:25     Packages to sync:                67
12:20:25     New packages to download:        67
12:20:25   Downloading packages:
12:20:25 Downloading total 67 files from 1 queues.
12:20:26     1/67 : containerd.io-1.3.7-3.1.el8.x86_64.rpm
12:20:29     2/67 : containerd.io-1.4.12-3.1.el8.x86_64.rpm
12:20:30     3/67 : containerd.io-1.4.10-3.1.el8.x86_64.rpm
12:20:30     4/67 : containerd.io-1.3.9-3.1.el8.x86_64.rpm
12:20:30     5/67 : containerd.io-1.4.13-3.1.el8.x86_64.rpm
12:20:32     6/67 : containerd.io-1.4.3-3.2.el8.x86_64.rpm
12:20:32     7/67 : containerd.io-1.4.6-3.1.el8.x86_64.rpm
12:20:33     8/67 : containerd.io-1.4.11-3.1.el8.x86_64.rpm
12:20:36     9/67 : containerd.io-1.4.8-3.1.el8.x86_64.rpm
12:20:36     10/67 : containerd.io-1.4.3-3.1.el8.x86_64.rpm
12:20:38     11/67 : containerd.io-1.4.4-3.1.el8.x86_64.rpm
12:20:39     12/67 : docker-ce-19.03.13-3.el8.x86_64.rpm
12:20:39     13/67 : containerd.io-1.4.9-3.1.el8.x86_64.rpm
12:20:42     14/67 : containerd.io-1.5.10-3.1.el8.x86_64.rpm
12:20:42     15/67 : docker-ce-19.03.14-3.el8.x86_64.rpm
12:20:42     16/67 : docker-ce-20.10.0-3.el8.x86_64.rpm
12:20:44     17/67 : docker-ce-19.03.15-3.el8.x86_64.rpm
12:20:44     18/67 : docker-ce-20.10.12-3.el8.x86_64.rpm
12:20:45     19/67 : docker-ce-20.10.10-3.el8.x86_64.rpm
12:20:47     20/67 : docker-ce-20.10.3-3.el8.x86_64.rpm
12:20:47     21/67 : docker-ce-20.10.1-3.el8.x86_64.rpm
12:20:48     22/67 : docker-ce-20.10.11-3.el8.x86_64.rpm
12:20:49     23/67 : docker-ce-20.10.2-3.el8.x86_64.rpm
12:20:49     24/67 : docker-ce-20.10.6-3.el8.x86_64.rpm
12:20:50     25/67 : docker-ce-20.10.13-3.el8.x86_64.rpm
12:20:52     26/67 : docker-ce-20.10.9-3.el8.x86_64.rpm
12:20:52     27/67 : docker-ce-20.10.4-3.el8.x86_64.rpm
12:20:53     28/67 : docker-ce-20.10.7-3.el8.x86_64.rpm
12:20:53     29/67 : docker-ce-20.10.8-3.el8.x86_64.rpm
12:20:56     30/67 : docker-ce-20.10.5-3.el8.x86_64.rpm
12:20:57     31/67 : docker-ce-cli-19.03.13-3.el8.x86_64.rpm
12:20:57     32/67 : docker-ce-cli-19.03.15-3.el8.x86_64.rpm
12:20:59     33/67 : docker-ce-cli-19.03.14-3.el8.x86_64.rpm
12:21:00     34/67 : docker-ce-cli-20.10.0-3.el8.x86_64.rpm
12:21:01     35/67 : docker-ce-cli-20.10.11-3.el8.x86_64.rpm
12:21:05     36/67 : docker-ce-cli-20.10.1-3.el8.x86_64.rpm
12:21:05     37/67 : docker-ce-cli-20.10.13-3.el8.x86_64.rpm
12:21:05     38/67 : docker-ce-cli-20.10.10-3.el8.x86_64.rpm
12:21:05     39/67 : docker-ce-cli-20.10.2-3.el8.x86_64.rpm
12:21:06     40/67 : docker-ce-cli-20.10.12-3.el8.x86_64.rpm
12:21:10     41/67 : docker-ce-cli-20.10.6-3.el8.x86_64.rpm
12:21:10     42/67 : docker-ce-cli-20.10.3-3.el8.x86_64.rpm
12:21:14     43/67 : docker-ce-cli-20.10.4-3.el8.x86_64.rpm
12:21:14     44/67 : docker-ce-rootless-extras-20.10.0-3.el8.x86_64.rpm
12:21:15     45/67 : docker-ce-cli-20.10.7-3.el8.x86_64.rpm
12:21:15     46/67 : docker-ce-rootless-extras-20.10.1-3.el8.x86_64.rpm
12:21:15     47/67 : docker-ce-rootless-extras-20.10.11-3.el8.x86_64.rpm
12:21:15     48/67 : docker-ce-rootless-extras-20.10.12-3.el8.x86_64.rpm
12:21:16     49/67 : docker-ce-rootless-extras-20.10.13-3.el8.x86_64.rpm
12:21:16     50/67 : docker-ce-rootless-extras-20.10.10-3.el8.x86_64.rpm
12:21:16     51/67 : docker-ce-cli-20.10.8-3.el8.x86_64.rpm
12:21:16     52/67 : docker-ce-cli-20.10.5-3.el8.x86_64.rpm
12:21:17     53/67 : docker-ce-rootless-extras-20.10.3-3.el8.x86_64.rpm
12:21:17     54/67 : docker-ce-rootless-extras-20.10.4-3.el8.x86_64.rpm
12:21:17     55/67 : docker-ce-rootless-extras-20.10.7-3.el8.x86_64.rpm
12:21:17     56/67 : docker-ce-rootless-extras-20.10.6-3.el8.x86_64.rpm
12:21:18     57/67 : docker-ce-rootless-extras-20.10.5-3.el8.x86_64.rpm
12:21:18     58/67 : docker-ce-rootless-extras-20.10.9-3.el8.x86_64.rpm
12:21:18     59/67 : docker-ce-rootless-extras-20.10.8-3.el8.x86_64.rpm
12:21:18     60/67 : docker-scan-plugin-0.17.0-3.el8.x86_64.rpm
12:21:18     61/67 : docker-scan-plugin-0.12.0-3.el8.x86_64.rpm
12:21:18     62/67 : docker-scan-plugin-0.7.0-3.el8.x86_64.rpm
12:21:18     63/67 : docker-ce-cli-20.10.9-3.el8.x86_64.rpm
12:21:18     64/67 : docker-compose-plugin-2.3.3-3.el8.x86_64.rpm
12:21:18     65/67 : docker-scan-plugin-0.8.0-3.el8.x86_64.rpm
12:21:18     66/67 : docker-scan-plugin-0.9.0-3.el8.x86_64.rpm
12:21:19     67/67 : docker-ce-rootless-extras-20.10.2-3.el8.x86_64.rpm
12:21:20 
12:21:20   Importing packages to DB:
12:22:19   Package batch #3 of 4 completed...
12:22:21   Package batch #4 of 4 completed...
12:22:21   Package batch #2 of 4 completed...
12:22:22   Package batch #1 of 4 completed...
12:22:22 
12:22:22   Linking packages to the channel.
12:22:22     67 packages linked
12:22:22 
12:22:22   Patches in repo: 0.
12:22:22   Regenerating bootstrap repositories.
Generating bootstrap repos for all available products which had changes.
Nothing to do.
12:22:23 Sync completed.
12:22:23 Total time: 0:01:59
```